# How to sort a Power BI visual by the values under each visual column?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Need a little bit of help in finishing my first Power Bi visual, with something that might be quite silly, apologies for the title being very confusing.

I have a table of data containing a list of codes, and each is associated to a country. I was interested just in the first characters of the codes and to find how many codes with the same first two characters are under each country.

Done the formatting by creating a column which only contains the relevant digits for each code. Also created a measure that calculates for each country count of how many codes of each type exist.

So I have in the visual Rows: Country, Columns: FormattedCode (Created Column), Values: CodeCount (Measure). The number of columns appearing in the visual is correlated with the number of distinct FormattedCodes.

| Country | AA | AB | AC | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Austria | 40 | 321 | 3 | 364 |
| Brazil | 236 | 689 | 11 | 936 |
| Canada | 150 | 2521 | 37 | 2573 |
| Denmark | 2 | 30506 | 21 | 30529 |
| Poland | 55 | 5612 | 7 | 5674 |
| Russia | 350 | 22031 | 91 | 22472 |

What I want is to be able to sort the visual on AA/AB/AC (say be able to sort descending on AA) The only sorting option existent of what I can see is by Total, which is not really what I need.

**1) What's the easiest way of doing this?**

**2) Is it possible to calculate the ratio of AA/AB?**

For the ration I created this measure:

```
Ratio = 
DIVIDE(
    CALCULATE(
        [CodeCount],
        'Table'[CodeCount] = "AA"
    ),
    CALCULATE(
        [CodeCount],
        'Table'[CodeCount] = "AB"
    )
)
```

My only issue is if I drag this into the visual it will appear next to each FormattedCode column, which is redundant since it's only calculating the one ratio.